# Why @HostBinding does not set class?

Tags: angular

I have binding in component:

```
@HostBinding('class.centered') public centered: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
   this.centered = true;
}
```

Styles:

```
:host {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

If inspect Google HTML I see that:

```
<app-map id="map" _nghost-ops-c160="" ng-version="10.2.5" class="centered" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></app-map>
```

Why class `.centered` is not applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming in this question, you are referring to the fact that the styling you expect to appear on the element `app-map` isn't appearing.

This is likely due to how you have structured your CSS. You can see that, in the HTML snipppet you showed, the element has `class="centered"`, which tells us that it has successfully applied that class to the element, but your CSS, as written, would only apply to an element *within* `app-map`. Your CSS would apply to the following structure:

```html
<app-map>
   <div class="centered"></>
</app-map>
```

To make this work how you'd expect, change your CSS to this:

```css
:host {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Notice there is no space between ":host" and ".centered"*/
:host.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

This specifies the following structure:

```html
<app-map class="centered"></app-map>
```